# Is it possible to override a single domain name using dnsmasq?

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, dnsmasq, spoofing

I have a server application that I'm running two instances of, production and development, namely:

```
prod.example.com (10.0.0.1)
dev.example.com (10.0.0.2)
```

A third-party has written a client application which has been hardcoded to point to `prod.example.com`. But, I want those requests to go to the `dev.example.com` server and I don't have access to the third-party source code.

I do have access (temporarily) to the LAN that the client and server are running on so I can use `dnsmasq` to resolve `prod.example.com` to `10.0.0.2`, at which point my work here is done and the client application will be (unknowingly) talking to the development server (or so I thought).

I've gotten as far as adding the following config to `dnsmasq.conf`..

```
address=/prod.example.com/10.0.0.2
```

..which does work, but it has the side-effect of preventing all other domains from resolving.

How can I have my cake and eat it?

Comment: Your side effect shouldn't happen. Nevertheless you can try editing `/etc/hosts`, or use `addn-hosts=` directive.

Comment: What do you suggest putting into `/etc/hosts`? Mine has a bunch of mappings between `127.0.0.1` and my local development URLs

Comment: `10.0.0.2 `prod.example.com`

Answer (score 11):

Add this line to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq.hosts
```

Then insert your domain names into `/etc/dnsmasq.hosts`:

```
10.0.0.1  prod.example.com.
10.0.0.2  dev.example.com.
```

Don't forget the period at the end of the domain name. It marks it as a TLD, not a local hostname.

As always after configuration changes, restart `dnsmasq`:

```
sudo service dnsmasq restart
```